# Why does my textbook say that $\int \tanh(x)\ dx=\ln(2\cosh(x))+C$?

Tags: integration

In my textbook there is an exercise to show that the entropy of a 2-state paramagnet is $$S=Nk[\ln(2\cosh(x)-x\tanh(x)]$$
I used $$S=\int{C_v\over T}dT$$ and in an earlier exercise I determined that $C_v=Nk\big({\mu B\over {kT}}\big)^2\bigg[\cosh^2\big({\mu B\over {kT}}\big)\bigg]^{-1}$, therefore

$$S=\int{Nk\over T}\big({\mu B\over {kT}}\big)^2\bigg[\cosh^2\big({\mu B\over {kT}}\big)\bigg]^{-1}dT$$

The integral needs to be in terms of $x$, so I say $x={\mu B\over {KT}}$. Then I do substitutions and get

$$S=-Nk\int{x\over {\cosh^2(x)}}dx=-Nk\int x \ {\sec}h^2(x)dx$$

After solving the integral using integration by parts, where $u=x$, $dv={\sec}h^2(x)$ and $v=\tanh(x)$, my result is

$$S=-Nk\big[x\tanh(x)-\ln(\cosh(x))+C\big]$$
However, the book claims that $\int \tanh(x) dx=\ln\big(2\cosh(x)\big)+C$. This would give me the result for entropy that I need, but I don't think $\int \tanh(x) dx=\ln\big(2\cosh(x)\big)+C$ is correct. I checked on Wolfram Alpha and $\int \tanh(x)dx=\ln(\cosh(x))$, this is also what the Wikipedia page on Hyperbolic functions says.

Is my book correct when it says $\int \tanh(x) dx=\ln\big(2\cosh(x)\big)+C$?

Comment: Up to a constant, they are the same.

Comment: $(\ln(2\cosh x))'=(\ln(2)+\ln(\cosh x))'=...$

Comment: @RobertWolfe Right, I know that property of logarithms, it just doesn't seem right to be that you can declare C=$\ln(2)$, because we don't know what it is. Wouldn't it be more proper to say that it's $\ln(C \cosh x)$?

Comment: At the end of the day, the differential equation will be solved, but expressed in possibly different---but equivalent---ways. Anybody not working with differential equations and still insisting on $C$ is being pedantic.

Comment: Hint from a physicist: what entropy do you expect when $x=0$?

Comment: @J.G. For a 2-state paramagnet I would expect it to be $\ln (2)$, so in that context it does make sense that the C is equal to that. Is it because of that that we can comfortably say that the constant is $\ln (2)$?